# Unable to resolve " not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header" when POSTing to api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created an api-gateway to put data in my s3 bucket. When I test it in console it works with no problem. Even when I test my token in the authorizer test it returns an "Allow", so there's nothing wrong with my token. My token validation is

```
^Bearer [-0-9a-zA-z\.]*$
```

so my python code for generating my header looks like this:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-type": "application/json"
}
```

The rest of my code is:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data={"id":"0678a93d-ee8c-4db5-a831-1e311be4f04b", "test":"12345"})
print(response.text)
```

The error message I get is 
"{"message":"'{My Token}' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer {My Token}'."}"

My url looks like this:

https://my-api-gateway.amazonaws.com/MyStage, and I am using a {proxy+} in my resources. I noticed if I change my header from Content-type to Accept, it gives me the same error, but if I also change my url to https://my-api-gateway.amazonaws.com/MyStage/any-arbitrary-string/, I get a

```
   {"response":{"status":"VALID", "message": "success"}}
```

but the file does not show up in my s3 bucket. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have `AWS_IAM` enabled on the S3 Bucket? If so then that requires your request be signed with [AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

Comment: I don't recall enabling that. How do I check/verify this?

Comment: I believe that if you use any user other than the main user you have it enabled as it is a user property. Here is more [info on IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html) and here is how to [call the API while using IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/programming.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved it. I changed my method to come from the root resource (instead of the unnecessary {proxy+}, and also noticed that my python method was incorrect. I had `response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=my_json)`, but data only accepts a string. I have to use either `requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=my_json)` or `requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=json.dumps(my_json))`

Comment: Removing the unnecessary /{Proxy+} for the POST endpoint saved my day. Note: {proxy+} works well for GET endpoints.

Answer (score 97):

I have run across this error when the resolved URL was incorrect. (Or without a proxy but with an incorrect URL.)

Comment: Also, check the method. It might be POST instead of GET, etc.

Comment: Web development has been around for so long. Why can't they make clear, accurate error messages? Anyway, thanks, this was the solution for my issue.

Comment: Cannot thank you enough: the AWS error message was hopeless debugging this. Lesson learned; don't trust the docs blindly.

Comment: Still happens to me when I forget to add "v1" to the base URL in Postman.

Comment: also caused by incorrect URL on my end, forgot a / in the middle. still an unexpected error message though.

Answer (score 19):

For me the reason why it didn't work is because I didn't redeploy when making changes to the integration.

So if you use terraform to create resources, you need to include the `triggers` part. See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_deployment.html#redeployment-triggers

If you're using UI, check:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same issue. For me, the issue was due to a case-sensitive url. Please make sure, the spelling and the casing of each of the words are correct.

Answer (score 3):

When using "{proxy+}" in the path, you also need to add a root path. Adding "{proxy+}" is how api gateway knows you are using Lambda proxy integration. So don't leave it out.

viz.,

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
       Events:
         ProxyResource:
           Type: Api
           Properties:
             RestApiId: ...
             Path: /{proxy+}
             Method: ANY
         RootResource:
           Type: Api
           Properties:
             RestApiId: ...
             Path: /
             Method: ANY
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case very similar,
using third api payment has wrong set on **request METHOD** , instead of DELETE I use POST. ah my bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using aws-api-gateway. 
 if the api is working fine in api-gateway of aws console and not working in the postman.

chances are `you might have forgotten to deploy your api in api gateway`

Answer (score 1):

for postman code generator , please make sure to remove unnecessary spaces from the URL , that was my issue

Answer (score 1):

in my case it worked when I replaced POST by PATCH

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
...
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
...
```

Comment: Also at times it can be CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',

Answer (score 1):

Along with [Will's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63019423/6187950), please also ensure the URL that you are calling is same case (lowercase or otherwise) as defined in API Gateway. The URL is case-sensitive

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33935738)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error occurred after I added the custom domain name to the API gateway.

Eventually, I discovered that the requested URL *"https://myapi.example.com/Prod/hello"* is incorrect. The stage name "Prod" should be removed from the URL since the custom domain name is already mapped to this stage. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when just running AWS.config.update. I had an extra space character and it gave this error. Just posting it here as it wasn't clear - but easily discoverable I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I chose wrong method.
Please check your request method

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was similarly an incorrect URL. My endpoint was meant to accept another URL as a path argument; and I'd applied Pyton's `urllib.parse.quote(url)` instead of `urllib.parse.quote_plus(url)`, so I was making requests to https://apigw.playground.sweet.io/gameplay/pack/https%3A//collectible.playground.sweet.io/series/BjqGOJqp instead of https://apigw.playground.sweet.io/gameplay/pack/https%3A%2F%2Fcollectible.playground.sweet.io%2Fseries%2FBjqGOJqp

Answer (score 0):

When I got this, I was being braindead and was hitting the apigateway root, and not an endpoint with a handler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message when I tried to get a inexistent endpoint to test my gateway.

I thought was token error, but no. This is caused because I dont had defined default gateways responses.

To solve, I create this code below, to add via terraform the same header to multiples errors/status code.

```
variable "http_responses" {
  type    = list(object({
    name          = string
    status_code   = string
    response_type = string
  }))
  default = [
    { name = "AccessDenied",                    status_code = "403", response_type = "ACCESS_DENIED" },
    { name = "ApiConfigurationError",           status_code = "500", response_type = "API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR" },
    { name = "AuthorizerConfigurationError",    status_code = "500", response_type = "AUTHORIZER_CONFIGURATION_ERROR" },
    { name = "AuthorizerFailure",               status_code = "500", response_type = "AUTHORIZER_FAILURE" },
    { name = "BadRequestBody",                  status_code = "400", response_type = "BAD_REQUEST_BODY" },
    { name = "BadRequestParameters",            status_code = "400", response_type = "BAD_REQUEST_PARAMETERS" },
    { name = "ExpiredToken",                    status_code = "403", response_type = "EXPIRED_TOKEN" },
    { name = "IntegrationFailure",              status_code = "500", response_type = "INTEGRATION_FAILURE" },
    { name = "IntegrationTimeout",              status_code = "504", response_type = "INTEGRATION_TIMEOUT" },
    { name = "InvalidApiKey",                   status_code = "403", response_type = "INVALID_API_KEY" },
    { name = "InvalidSignature",                status_code = "403", response_type = "INVALID_SIGNATURE" },
    { name = "MissingAuthenticationToken",      status_code = "403", response_type = "MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN" },
    { name = "QuotaExceeded",                   status_code = "429", response_type = "QUOTA_EXCEEDED" },
    { name = "RequestTooLarge",                 status_code = "413", response_type = "REQUEST_TOO_LARGE" },
    { name = "ResourceNotFound",                status_code = "404", response_type = "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND" },
    { name = "Throttled",                       status_code = "429", response_type = "THROTTLED" },
    { name = "Unauthorized",                    status_code = "401", response_type = "UNAUTHORIZED" },
    { name = "UnsupportedMediaType",            status_code = "415", response_type = "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE" },
    { name = "WafFiltered",                     status_code = "403", response_type = "WAF_FILTERED" },
    { name = "DEFAULT_4XX",                     status_code = "", response_type = "DEFAULT_4XX" },
    { name = "DEFAULT_5XX",                     status_code = "", response_type = "DEFAULT_5XX" },

  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_gateway_response" "http_responses" {
  for_each = { for response in var.http_responses : "${response.name}-${response.status_code}" => response }

  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id
  status_code   = each.value.status_code
  response_type = each.value.response_type

  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = "{\"message\":$context.error.messageString}"
  }

  response_parameters = {
    "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
    "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS'"
    "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = "'*'"

  }
}
```

Now, when I try to get an inexistent endpoint, I get this response:

```
   {
   "field" : null,
   "exceptionClass" : "ResponseStatusException",
   "message" : "field não encontrado",
   "statusCode" : 404,
   "statusText" : "404 NOT_FOUND"
}
```

Is it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to access API gateway via Postman by using OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant, it always returns this error message. Unfortunately if method authorization is set to AWS_IAM, you can not make this API call via pPostman.

[image]

You can remove Authorization until you tested your endpoint via Postman.